# A very strange behaviour of filesystem, Schrödinger's file

Tags: files, permissions, git, macos, touch

I'm fresh to Unix, and I would like to have your help with this strange behavior

I have a user directory /Users/den

```
den$ ls -la
total 208
drwxrwx---+ 19 den   staff    608 18 Jan 16:35 .
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  admin    160 30 Oct 16:04 ..
-rwxrwx---   1 den   staff      3 17 Jan 17:57 .CFUserTextEncoding
drwxrwx---   2 den   staff     64 18 Jan 15:35 .Trash
-rwxrwx---   1 den   staff  11976 18 Jan 15:43 .bash_history
-rwxrwx---   1 den   staff    438 17 Jan 20:34 .bash_profile
drwxrwx---   3 den   staff     96 18 Jan 15:36 .bash_sessions
-rwxrwx---   1 den   staff  78473 17 Jan 20:28 .git-completion.bash
-rwxrwx---   1 den   staff    595 18 Jan 00:26 .zsh_history
drwxrwx---+  4 den   staff    128 17 Jan 19:00 Desktop
drwxrwx---+  4 den   staff    128 17 Jan 20:46 Documents
drwxrwx---+  3 den   staff     96 17 Jan 17:57 Downloads
drwxrwx---@ 56 den   staff   1792 18 Jan 15:35 Library
drwxrwx---+  3 den   staff     96 17 Jan 17:57 Movies
drwxrwx---+  3 den   staff     96 17 Jan 17:57 Music
drwxrwx---+  4 den   staff    128 17 Jan 18:12 Pictures
drwxrwx---+  4 den   staff    128 17 Jan 17:57 Public
```

In that directory, I'm trying to create a config file for git

```
192:~ den$ touch .gitconfig
touch: .gitconfig: No such file or directory
```

If I try to `touch` anything else, for example, `.gitconfig1`

```
192:~ den$ touch .gitconfig1
192:~ den$ ls -la
total 208
drwxrwx---+ 20 den   staff    640 18 Jan 16:55 .
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  admin    160 30 Oct 16:04 ..
-rwxrwx---   1 den   staff      3 17 Jan 17:57 .CFUserTextEncoding
drwxrwx---   2 den   staff     64 18 Jan 15:35 .Trash
-rwxrwx---   1 den   staff  11976 18 Jan 15:43 .bash_history
-rwxrwx---   1 den   staff    438 17 Jan 20:34 .bash_profile
drwxrwx---   3 den   staff     96 18 Jan 15:36 .bash_sessions
-rwxrwx---   1 den   staff  78473 17 Jan 20:28 .git-completion.bash
-rw-r--r--   1 den   staff      0 18 Jan 16:55 .gitconfig1
-rwxrwx---   1 den   staff    595 18 Jan 00:26 .zsh_history
drwxrwx---+  4 den   staff    128 17 Jan 19:00 Desktop
drwxrwx---+  4 den   staff    128 17 Jan 20:46 Documents
drwxrwx---+  3 den   staff     96 17 Jan 17:57 Downloads
drwxrwx---@ 56 den   staff   1792 18 Jan 15:35 Library
drwxrwx---+  3 den   staff     96 17 Jan 17:57 Movies
drwxrwx---+  3 den   staff     96 17 Jan 17:57 Music
drwxrwx---+  4 den   staff    128 17 Jan 18:12 Pictures
drwxrwx---+  4 den   staff    128 17 Jan 17:57 Public
```

I can create it with no problem, only `.gitconfig` itself is untouchable.

Another interesting thing that I observed, that if I try to autocomplete .git in that folder, it actually suggests me `.gitconfig` as one of the options.

```
192:~ den$ nano .git
.git-completion.bash  .gitconfig            .gitconfig1           
192:~ den$ nano .git
```

Do you have any thoughts on what may be happenening?

Comment: Is this a physical Linux-based system, or a VM, or something layered on top of and part of Windows?

Comment: @roaima It's a freshly installed macOS on a formatted drive of a macbook. So far the best explanation that I came up with is that it's a drive malfunction. All other things seem to be in the right places.

Comment: Similar problem on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28143027/4500798) (with no explanation).

Comment: @roaima valid questions, indeed, I intended to write Unix but typed Linux (don't really know why). In the end, it was a macOS problem, but that was not obvious from the beginning, since I was experienced the error while executing the Unix command.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was file system corruption beyond repairability.

It was a macOS specific problem: `fsroot root tree is invalid`

Thanks everyone for your suggestions

---

as per @Kusalananda request, the steps that I took. **Note: only applies to macOS.**

Boot into recovery mode *(recommended so you would be able to unmount a boot drive)* by pressing CMD + R during MacOS startup

execute `diskutil list` and observe your drives

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *240.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         239.8 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *120.0 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS SSD                     119.7 GB   disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +239.8 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume main                    11.1 GB    disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 24.3 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                525.8 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk2s4
   5:                APFS Volume main - Data             10.1 GB    disk2s5
```

what you need is located in `IDENTIFIER` column

take value from it (disk0s1...) and run it over

```
diskutil verifyVolume <IDENTIFIER>
```

example: `diskutil verifyVolume disk0s1`

for me, once I run it over `disk0s2` I got

```
fsroot tree is invalid
The volume /dev/disk0s2 could not be verified completely
```

If that is your boot drive, you need to unmount it before performing the next action

```
diskutil unmount <volume>
```

like `diskutil unmount /dev/disk0s2`

now go back to the disks list and find out what format is set for this identifier.

in my example, it was `Apple_APFS Container disk2` which means it's in APFS format.

now you need to run `fsck_<file format> -y <broken volume>`

since in my case the format for the drive is `APFS` and I need to repair `/dev/disk0s2` it goes as:

```
fsck_apfs -y /dev/disk0s2
```

for reference

```
fsck_apfs [ [-q | -n | -y] [-l] [-s] [-S] [-o] ] device
       -q            quick check if the superblock and checkpoint superblock are valid.
       -n            verify only (answer "no" to questions)
       -y            always repair (answer "yes" to questions)
       -l            live fsck (lock down for verify-only)
       -s            print space verification summary
       -S            skip iteration of snapshots, although no repairs can be made.
       -o            repair overallocations; please do not run an older fsck_apfs on newer systems with this option
```

Now, if you're lucky enough, your problem may be resolved. Unfortunately for me, this command still returned an error. Perhaps there is another way to fix the drive mapping which I'm not aware of. I just choose the easy path and formatted the drive, after that, the problem went away.

Comment: Could you say something about how to fix it, or how you're dealing with it?

Comment: @Kusalananda here you go